# KnockoutJS: applying same ViewModel to multiple divs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a div that can be duplicated over and over. I want to use KO to bind a new ViewModel instance to every new div instance. I cannot understand how this is possible just by reading the tutorials and going through examples.

Consider this:

```
<div id="div1">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
</div>

<script>
    function ViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Test");
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

This will bind the input fields on both divs to the *same* ViewModel object. To rephrase, what I want to do is bind a new instance of the ViewModel to every div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly written in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html)

> Optionally, you can pass a second parameter to define which part of the document you want 
>   to search for data-bind attributes. For example, **ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, 
>   document.getElementById('someElementId'))**. This restricts the activation to the element 
>   with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple 
>   view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

So, considering your example:

```
<div id="div1">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input data-bind="value: firstName" />
</div>

<script>
    function ViewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Test");
    }

    var vm1 = new ViewModel();
    var vm2 = new ViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('div1'));
    ko.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById('div2'));

    vm2.firstName("Archie");
</script>
```

Comment: I had gone through several pages of the documentation hoping to find a section for "applyBinding" but there was none. The paragraph that you pointed out is buried within a different topic all together. Anyway, it seems that your code will do the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I sound obnoxious, but the paragraph is in the topic "Activating Knockout", it couldn't be in a better topic in my opinion.

Comment: KO has been working for me, so I thought I had already done the "activation" bit. But I get your point. Overall KO seems quite complete and well though through. I am actually stoked to see that there's a 2nd parameter!

Comment: Related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/203046/multiple-knockout-uicomponents-should-not-share-the-same-data